# A specific form of the Hamburger Problem

Tags: probability, moment-problem

I'm having a hard time trying to solve a moment-related problem.
Let M be a random variable, I denote  its k-th moment $m_{k}(X)=E({X^k})$ .
How can i prove that the sequence $ u_{k}=\frac{m_{k+2n}(X)}{m_{2n}(X)} $  defines the k-th moment of another random variable, Y ?
I shall not use any tool from measure theory, and the variable X doesn't necesserily have a density. I tried to use the algebric characterization using Henkel matrices, which proved to be a deadlock. Carlman's criterium isn't helpful either.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed? ${}$

Comment: I'd look again at the Hankel matrix characterization.

Comment: Yes, n is fixed

Comment: But the Hankel Matrix characterization leads me to an algebric problem, i.e to show that it is a positive definite matrix, knowing that the hankel matrix associated with X is definitive positive. I tried to do an induction on k, but it doesn't work. Do you think it is only a summation problem, i.e changing indexes etc ?

Comment: I found the answer myself : it's obviously true because $$E(({X^{n}}(\sum_{i=1}^k α_{i}X^i))^2) ⩾ 0 $$